# Renumbering files in a folder consecutively

Tags: python, beginner, file-system

I wrote a program to rename files with consecutive numbers, basically removing the gaps in the numbering. This could be a very annoying task to do it manually in windows. I only did this for practicing Python purposes.

Lets show what the program does in an example:

Say you have a folder `E:\Spam` which contains the following files:

> eggs010.txt  
>   spam00.txt 
>  spam002.txt  
>  spam004.txt
>   
>  spam005.txt 
>     spam5.dat
>  spam7.txt  
> spam009.txt
>   
>  spam037.txt 
>  spam045.txt
>      spam089.txt 
>   spam2000.txt

Lets say for what reason you want to continues numbe all the files from type 
`spam.txt`

After running my program it gives out this:

> eggs010.txt (unchanged wrong filename) 
>  spam0001.txt  
>   spam0002.txt  
>  spam0003.txt  
>  spam0004.txt  
>   spam0005.txt  
>  spam5.dat (unchanged wrong filetype) 
>   spam0006.txt  
>  spam0007.txt  
>  spam0008.txt  
>   spam0009.txt  
>  spam0010.txt

Also an offset can be added to start the numbering for example at 5 or 0 instead of.

filling_gaps.py

```
"""
Filling_gaps.
Removes gaps in numbering of multiple files in a specified directory.

Takes a directory to search for files which match prefix and type and
otherwise only contain numbers in the middle.
Files are renamed continuesyly and filled up with leading zeros if
necessary
It is possible to define with which number the numeration
starts

e.g.
spam001.txt
spam003.txt
spam013.txt
spam1180.txt

would become (if start_number = 1):

spam0001.txt
spam0002.txt
spam0003.txt
spam0004.txt

To prevent overriting in the renaming process a temporary directory is
created during the renaming.
"""

import os
import sys
import shutil
import stat
from typing import List

def get_filenames(directory: str) -> List[str]:
    """
    get filenames in supplied absolute directory name
    """
    os.chdir(directory)
    return os.listdir('.')


def get_digits_minimum_length(filenames: List[str], file_prefix: str,
                              file_type: str, start_number: int) -> int:
    """
    loops over all provided filenames to find the filename with the
    longest digit string e.g:
    spam00001.txt   -> len = 5
    spam02.txt      -> len = 2
    spam0000003.txt -> len = 7
    digits_length == 7
    """
    digits_length: int = 0
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.startswith(file_prefix) and filename.endswith(file_type):
            number_string: str = filename.lstrip(file_prefix)
            number_string = number_string.rstrip(file_type)
            if number_string.isdigit():
                current_length = len(number_string)
                if current_length > digits_length:
                    digits_length = current_length

    if len(str(start_number)) > digits_length:
        digits_length = start_number

    return digits_length


def make_filename(file_prefix: str, file_type: str, number: int,
                  number_length: int) -> str:
    """
    Creates a new filename out of the parts.
    """
    return file_prefix + str(number).zfill(number_length) + file_type


def make_folder(directory: str, folder_name: str):
    """
    Creates a folder inside a directory
    """
    new_directory: str = os.path.join(directory, folder_name)
    os.makedirs(new_directory)
    os.chmod(new_directory, stat.S_IWRITE)


def rename_and_move_file(directory: str, new_directory: str,
                         old_filename: str, new_filename: str):
    """
    Renames a file from a specific directory into a new directory to
    prevent that renamoving overrites other existing files
    """
    shutil.move(os.path.join(directory, old_filename),
                os.path.join(new_directory, new_filename))


def erase_directory(delete_directory: str):
    """
    checks if directory exists and deletes it.
    """
    if os.path.exists(delete_directory):
        shutil.rmtree(delete_directory)


def extract_digits_and_move_to_temp(
        directory: str, temp_directory: str, file_prefix: str, file_type: str,
        digit_lenght: int):
    """
    Remove pre und postfix from files, add leading zeros to the
    integer part to reach the same length for all digitsand copy them
    to temp directory
    """
    for filename in get_filenames(directory):
        if filename.startswith(file_prefix) and filename.endswith(file_type):
            number_string: str = filename.lstrip(file_prefix)
            number_string = number_string.rstrip(file_type)
            if number_string.isdigit():
                rename_and_move_file(directory, temp_directory, filename,
                                     number_string.zfill(digit_lenght))


def renumber_and_move_to_directory(
        start_number: int, directory: str, temp_directory: str,
        file_prefix: str, file_type: str, digit_lenght: int):
    """
    Renumbers the files according to start file number and moves them
    back to directory
    """
    next_number: int = start_number
    filenames = get_filenames(temp_directory)
    filenames.sort()
    for filename in filenames:
        new_filename: str = make_filename(
            file_prefix, file_type, next_number, digit_lenght)
        rename_and_move_file(temp_directory, directory, filename, new_filename)
        next_number = next_number + 1


def filling_gaps(directory: str, file_prefix: str, file_type: str,
                 start_number: int = 1):
    """
    Main logic of the filling gaps script.
    First a temporary directory is made for the file operations.
    Then the max len of digits (int + leading zeros) is calculated out
    of the files.
    Then all matched files are stripped everything but the int part and
    they are moved into the temp directory.
    In the temp directory they are numerated correctly again and moved
    back to the source directory.
    In the end the temporary directory is deleted
    """
    if start_number < 0:
        raise Exception("Start file number must be >=0. Value: " +
                        str(start_number))

    temp_folder_name = "temp"
    temp_directory = os.path.join(directory, temp_folder_name)

    if os.path.exists(temp_directory):
        print("Error: temp directory used for internal copy already exists."
              " Make sure it does not. directory name:" + temp_folder_name)
        sys.exit(0)

    make_folder(directory, temp_folder_name)

    digits_length: int = get_digits_minimum_length(
        get_filenames(directory), file_prefix, file_type, start_number)

    extract_digits_and_move_to_temp(
        directory, temp_directory, file_prefix, file_type, digits_length)

    renumber_and_move_to_directory(
        start_number, directory, temp_directory, file_prefix, file_type,
        digits_length)

    erase_directory(temp_directory)


filling_gaps("E:\\Spam", "spam", ".txt", 1)
```

I would like to know if this is good code?
Is the approach a good one?
Do you understand the code from the comments and the docstrings?
Are there any bad practices you can spot
Are there any improvements / better approaches to try?

Also I tested this script by manually adding the example script again and again how could this be better tested?

Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Bug

You have a two bugs in `get_digits_minimum_length()`:

> ```
> if len(str(start_number)) > digits_length:
>     digits_length = start_number
> ```

First of all, you probably meant `digits_length = len(start_number)`.  But even that is not enough, because the end number might have more digits than the starting number.  Therefore, it should be:

```
digits_length = max(digits_length, len(str(start_number + len(filenames) - 1)))
```

### File manipulation

A better way to make a temporary directory within `directory` is [`tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=directory)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp).  It guarantees that the name of the new directory will not collide with any existing file or directory.  (It automatically generates a different name as necessary to make that happen.)

The temporary directory needs to have permissions `stat.S_IRWXU`.  On Unix, `stat.S_IWRITE` (or `stat.IWUSR`) is insufficient, since you will not be able to call `listdir()` on the temporary directory.

The program calls `get_filenames()` three times.  Not only is that slow and wasteful, it also presents a possibility for inconsistencies due to race conditions, if a file gets created or removed while the program is running.

`shutil.move()` is overkill, when `os.rename()` should work just as well.  Also, it would be better to just do `os.rmdir()` rather than `shutil.rmtree()` to clean up the temporary directory, because `os.rmdir()` asserts that the directory is empty.  (You wouldn't want to accidentally delete any of your files, would you? And if you did want to force a cleanup, [`with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temporary_directory: …`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) would be a more elegant way to write it.)

### Global state

`os.chdir()` affects the global state of a process.  I'd try to avoid doing it at all, if possible.  And if you do do it, then I'd call it from a prominent place in your code, so that some innocuous-looking utility function (`get_filenames()`) does not have unexpected insidious side-effects on the rest of your code.  After calling `os.chdir()`, you don't have to ever mention `directory` again in your code anymore, because every operation is relative to the current directory.

### Design and efficiency

I am slightly annoyed by some of your very short helper functions: `make_filename()`, `make_folder()`, and `erase_directory()`.  In my opinion, they make the code harder to read, because they add very little value over the standard library call, but I have to devote mental effort into keeping track of what they do.  Each of those functions is called from just one place, which makes their existence even less worthwhile.

I imagine that there might be use cases where this program is repeatedly executed for some directory.  In that case, you would be moving files into and out of the temporary directory, most of them for naught.  A better strategy would be to **put more work into mapping the source filenames into their desired destinations** (as in my `filename_map()` below), so that no more filesystem manipulation is done than necessary.

### Suggested solution

```
import os
import re
import stat
import tempfile

def filename_map(prefix, suffix, start_number):
    """
    Make a dictionary that maps source filenames to their renumbered
    destination filename.
    """
    pattern = re.compile(re.escape(prefix) + '([0-9]+)' + re.escape(suffix), re.I)
    num_to_fn = {
        pattern.fullmatch(fn).group(1): fn
        for fn in os.listdir()
        if pattern.fullmatch(fn)
    }
    digits_length = max(
        max((len(num) for num in num_to_fn), default=0),
        len(str(start_number + len(num_to_fn) - 1))
    )
    return {
        num_to_fn[num]: prefix + str(i).zfill(digits_length) + suffix
        for i, num in enumerate(sorted(num_to_fn, key=int), start_number)
    }

def filling_gaps(prefix, suffix, start_number=1):
    """
    Rename files in the current directory whose names consist of the given
    prefix, followed by some digits, and the given suffix, such that they
    are consecutively numbered from the specified start_number.
    """
    if start_number < 0:
        raise ArgumentError("Start number {0} is less than 0", start_number)

    fn_map = {
        src_fn: dst_fn
        for src_fn, dst_fn in filename_map(prefix, suffix, start_number).items()
        if src_fn != dst_fn
    }
    if not fn_map:
        return  # Nothing to rename

    temp_directory = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir='.', prefix='renumber')
    os.chmod(temp_directory, stat.S_IRWXU)
    for src_fn, dst_fn in fn_map.items():
        os.rename(src_fn, os.path.join(temp_directory, dst_fn))
    for dst_fn in fn_map.values():
        os.rename(os.path.join(temp_directory, dst_fn), dst_fn)
    os.rmdir(temp_directory)

os.chdir(r'E:\spam')
filling_gaps('spam', '.txt', 1)
```

Comment: `prefix + str(i).zfill(digits_length) + suffix` could be `f"{prefix}{i:0{digits_length}}{suffix}"` as an f-string.

Answer (score 2):

## Indenting

I don't like this style

```
def get_digits_minimum_length(filenames: List[str], file_prefix: str,
                              file_type: str, start_number: int) -> int:
```

I'm more a fan of

```
def get_digits_minimum_length(
    filenames: List[str], file_prefix: str, file_type: str, start_number: int
) -> int:
```

...

or

```
def get_digits_minimum_length(
    filenames: List[str], 
    file_prefix: str, 
    file_type: str, 
    start_number: int,
) -> int:
    ...
```

But since recently, I use a code formatter ([black](https://github.com/ambv/black)) to do this

## `Pathlib.Path`

Using `pathlib.Path` instead of `os` can make things a lot easier. It has builtin globbing, and you can easily generate the new name

## separate the program

All in all this is a rather simple program:

1. Find the files who are structured `"{prefix}{number}.{suffix}"`
2. Extract `number`
3. Generate a new number
4. Generate the new name
5. Move the files

Your program makes a few strange splits between the functions.

If you need to do this via a temporary directory, use [`tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) as a context manager

All in all this can be done quite simple

```
def find_files(directory, prefix, suffix):
    """find the files in `directory` wich start with `prefix` and end with `.suffix`"""
    directory = Path(directory)

    filename_pattern = re.compile(
        re.escape(prefix) + "(?P<number>[0-9]+)\." + re.escape(suffix), re.I
    )
    for file in directory.glob(f"{prefix}*.{suffix}"):
        match = filename_pattern.search(file.name)
        if not match:
            continue
        yield int(match.group("number")), file
```

This generator yield the number (as `int`) and the filename (as `Path`) of all the files that comply with the prefix and suffix

```
def rename_files(files, prefix, suffix, start_num=0):
    """Generates the new filename"""
    files = sorted(files)
    last_file_num = files[-1][0]
    max_num = max(last_file_num, start_num + len(files))
    num_length = len(str(max_num))
    for new_number, (_, file) in enumerate((files), start_num):
        new_name = f"{prefix}{str(new_number).zfill(num_length)}.{suffix}"
        yield file, new_name
```

This one yields the file and the new proposed name. To calculate how long the number needs to be, it takes into account the lingest existing number and the starting number + amount of files to rename.

It also keeps the existing order, ordered via the number, not lexigraphically, so `spam1.txt` comes before `spam02.txt`

the method to move the files takes this generator as input, and does the moving on the fly:

```
def move(renames, practice=True):
    for file, new_name in renames:
        new_file = file.with_name(new_name)
        print(f"renaming {file.name} to {new_name}")
        if not practice:
            os.rename(file, new_file)
```

This was tested with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    prefix = "spam"
    suffix = "txt"
    files = find_files(DATA_DIR, prefix, suffix)
    renames = rename_files(files, prefix, suffix)
    move(renames, practice=False)
```

> ```
> renaming spam00.txt to spam0000.txt
> renaming spam002.txt to spam0001.txt
> renaming spam004.txt to spam0002.txt
> renaming spam005.txt to spam0003.txt
> renaming spam7.txt to spam0004.txt
> renaming spam009.txt to spam0005.txt
> renaming spam037.txt to spam0006.txt
> renaming spam045.txt to spam0007.txt
> renaming spam089.txt to spam0008.txt
> renaming spam2000.txt to spam0009.txt
> ```

I tested this with:

```
DATA_DIR = Path("data/test")
testfiles = """eggs010.txt
spam00.txt
spam002.txt
spam004.txt
spam005.txt
spam5.dat
spam7.txt
spam009.txt
spam037.txt
spam045.txt
spam089.txt
spam2000.txt"""

for filename in testfiles.split("\n"):
    file = DATA_DIR / filename.strip()
    file.touch()
```